# Home/end keys are not working correctly in the bash CLI for a jailed user using PuTTY

Tags: terminal, putty, chroot

I'm using PuTTY to access my U14.04 LTS server via SSH.

When I log in using my main account, the number pad keys work fine in the BASH CLI.

When I log in to a user who's been jailed using Jailkit, the home/end keys return a '~' character and bell in the CLI (Pgup, PgDn also do the same). Although these keys are working fine when I'm editing a file using nano, for example.

My `$TERM` variable is set to '`xterm`', and I've copied '`.bashrc`' from my main account to this user, so folders are showing in their normal colors and aliases are working.

Can someone advice me, what I'm missing in the jail that is preventing the keyboard from being configured correctly? Maybe a binary isn't accessible from the jail, or a config setting for the user?

Comment: check the language settings, and the login shell.

Comment: thnx Dennis, how would I do that?  What file?  The PuTTY settings are identical, so it's something on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in the terminal settings, they are surely o.k., because nano and other ncurses programs work.

The problem is nearly surely on the command line things, which are handled by the readline library. Its configuration file named as `inputrc`. It can be found either in `/etc/inputrc`, or in `~/.inputrc` in your home. The first is or isn't copied by your jailkit, the second is probably not.

Check the availability and the contents of the `inputrc` in your root (not-jailed) file hierarchy, and its availability in your jail as well.

Comment: thanks.  I have no `~/inputrc` in my normal user account, and after using `jk_cp` of `/etc/inputrc` to the jail, it's fixed.